# Rename the email notifications titles in woocommerce admin settings panel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, title, email-notifications

A simple question: How can I rename the WooCommerce email template names under WooCommerce -> E-Mails?

[image]

For example:

Old: Neue Bestellung
New: New Title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rename Email notification titles, you will use the following *(replacing them by yours)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_title', 'change_woocommerce_email_title', 10, 2 );
function change_woocommerce_email_title( $email_title, $email ){

    // Only on backend Woocommerce Settings "Emails" tab
    if( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'wc-settings' && isset($_GET['tab'])  && $_GET['tab'] == 'email' ) {

        $domain = "woocommerce"; // The text domain

        switch ($email->id) {

            case 'new_order':
                $email_title = __("New Order Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'cancelled_order':
                $email_title = __("Cancelled Order Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'failed_order':
                $email_title = __("Failed Order", $domain);
                break;

            case 'customer_on_hold_order':
                $email_title = __("Customer On Hold Order Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'customer_processing_order':
                $email_title = __("Customer Processing Order Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'customer_completed_order':
                $email_title = __("Customer Completed Order Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'customer_refunded_order':
                $email_title = __("Customer Refunded Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'customer_invoice':
                $email_title = __("Customer Invoice Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'customer_note':
                $email_title = __("Customer note Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'customer_reset_password':
                $email_title = __("Customer Reset Password Email", $domain);
                break;

            case 'customer_new_account':
                $email_title = __("Customer New Account Email", $domain);
                break;
        }
    }

    return $email_title;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Just to clarify, Is my answer valid or forbidden ?

Comment: I haven't somehow seen this filter there. Great solution.

Comment: I too posted an answer for the same question. Can you please check ?

Comment: @melvin The `woocommerce_email_title` filter hook is specifically added by Woocommerce to alter / change the email notification titles. Now your answer code might work, but it might be something much more heavier.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it works but in each order in the dropdown where I can sent the email I see still the old name :|

Comment: Why? I expected that when I change the name of the templates that the same templates in the dropdown are the same. But ok. I'll ask a new question :)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec can you checkout my new post? I'll add the code there which displays the widget but I don't know how to hook in to add emails there or rename the current one.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec As I can see in the function which returns the emails for the widget the title is getting from the same field you changed with your function but as I can see it has no effect for the dropdown

Comment: @Mr.Jo No it hasn't… it just change the display when the displayed email title uses the `WC_Email` method `get_title()` as this filter hook is inside it.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec hmm okay. Sad but ok.